# Issue with gdal getprojection and setprojection returning different information

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I am using Landsat imagery from the USGS. Those who use them may know that the projection attribute is wrong (everything is in the Northern hemisphere). 
I have a script to process tar.gz files and output a stacklayer with selected bands of interest. I deal with the projection error by modifying the EPSG value and writing a new projection like this:

```
orgeoproj =  dst.GetProjection() # North projection
osn = osr.SpatialReference()
osn.ImportFromWkt(dst.GetProjection())
nEPSG= int(osn.GetAttrValue("AUTHORITY",1))
sEPSG= nEPSG + 100
print "mudando EPSG Norte a Sur"
osn.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:%d"%sEPSG)
modgeoproj = osn.ExportToWkt()
```

When I print `orgeoproj` (original geoproject), the output has Authority values like:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 23N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32623"]]
```

After modifying the EPSG value, the `modgeoproj` is OK now and showing the right EPSG value for the southern hemisphere! The problem rises when I write the `modgeoproj` with `SetProjection`(modgeoproj) to the stacklayer and then load it with another script.

After a `GetProjection()`, I only get:

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_23S",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

There's no Authority Information and I need it!
What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: what gdal version?

Comment: gdal version: 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Geotif format stores the EPSG code, or the whole projection definition in WKT or proj. If you compare the wo definitions:

```
D:\Karten\gdal\gdal-1-11>gdalsrsinfo EPSG:32623

PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=23 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 23N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32623"]]


D:\Karten\gdal\gdal-1-11>gdalsrsinfo EPSG:32723

PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 23S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32723"]]
```

you see that the UTM 23S has a different false_northing value. So you may have to alter that value too.

Comment: I am letting the osr modulo to handle that. I simply get the wrong EPSG code from the single band tif images stored in the tar.gz package, modify the code to the correct one and then pass it to the osr to construct the correct projection parameters. I am modifying the geotransform by adding 10.000.000 to the false_northing parameter if that is what you mean.

Comment: And GTiff does stores all the information about the projection (params and authorities), because I am reading the wrong one from them. I am just not been able to store the correct one back with all the information I need!